# Async and EhCache is not working for the second user logging in

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, ehcache, future

I am trying to implement @async with @cacheable as below ..

```
@RequestMapping(value="ehcacheExample")
public ModelAndView loadehcacheExamplePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

    cacheHelper.getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(userInfo, session);

    //diffetent execution
    ...

    return modelAndView;
}
```

And

```
@Cacheable(value="cacheKey")
public Future<String> getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(UserLoginSessionInfo userInfo,
        HttpSession session) {
    return ehcacheExampleDelegate.getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(userInfo,session);
}
```

> 

```
@Async
public Future<String> getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(UserLoginSessionInfo userInfo, 
    HttpSession session) {

    //Async execution
    return new AsyncResult<String>(jsonInString);
}
```

Now as per my understanding this 'getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache' method  produces the result independent of the caller method,saves it in ehcache implementation. So, the next time I call an ajax method for getting the data from future, I am doing below implementation -

```
@RequestMapping(value="getCachedData")
    public @ResponseBody String getCachedData(HttpSession session) {
        UserLoginSessionInfo userInfo = HttpRequestSessionUtils.getLoggedinUserSessionInfo(session);

        Future<String> cachedData = cacheHelper.getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(userInfo, session);
        …
        return dataFromFuture; 

    }
```

Now my expectation is, if any other user logs in after the first user, for him  `cacheHelper.getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(userInfo, session)` should not execute the whole method. Rather it should retrieve the data from Ehcache memory.

But it is not happening. I can assure that caching is working because in the same session if the user calls the getCachedData ajax call multiple times, it is returning the data from cache only. But the issue is happening with the `cacheHelper.getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache(userInfo, session)` implementation (mentioned in the `@RequestMapping(value="ehcacheExample")` method).

Can you please help me understand why this method is executing in whole, everytime the user calls `loadehcacheExamplePage` method rather than retrieving it from cache when a second user logging in?

Comment: What do you mean by "why this method is executing in whole everytime" ?  What exactly does "whole" mean?

Comment: I meant to say.. it is not retrieving the data from cache which i expected rather it is again going into the method getDataUsingAsyncAndStoreInEhcache , doing all the business logic processing , calling the soap service for data and then returning the data back. That is the whole process i meant

Answer (score 0):

I see different possible issues here. First, there is a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15915) between caching and async in Spring. However, I don't think it is relevant to you since your `CacheHelper` and `CacheHelperDelegate` are not the same object.

Now, it's the `Future` that will get cached. Not the value returned by it. It's weird. But it should still work.

Finally, Spring uses by default the parameters as the cache key. In your case `UserLoginSessionInfo userInfo, HttpSession session`. These are highly user specific. So it's normal that for two different users, the method will be called. If that's not what you want, you probably do not need to pass these parameters. You can also tell Spring what to use as a key with `@Cacheable(key=...)`.